# How to keep row header on each page in SSRS but I'm unable to select the top left cell of the tablix in the designer mode

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

For some reason my static fields in a Row Groups do not locate the cell Rank or Producer, which are the rows that I want to display on each page.
I tried to set `KeepWithGroup` on Column Groups but it gives me an error. 
What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.Right-click the row, column, or corner handle of a tablix data region, and then click Tablix Properties.
2.On the General tab, under Row Headers or Column Headers, select Header should remain visible while scrolling.
3.Click OK.